# Dynamically add variable to this in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create one remove function to remove items from different array. My function is like this, which accepts array name and index of the item in that array.

```
removeItem(itemArray, index){
   this.itemArray.splice(index,1);
}
```

Then use it like

```
removeItem('selectedColors',5);
```

But `this` does not catch my variable name. In console I get `this.itemArray .splice is not a function`
I also tried like this, I created a itemArray variable so I could assign it. Well, did not work as well.

```
removeItem(itemArray, index){
   this.itemArray = itemArray;
   this.itemArray.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without `this`?

Comment: so dot vs bracket notation? `this[itemArray].splice`

Comment: 'this' references the context from which you call the function from, not the function itself. You don't need it when using variables that are passed into the function

Comment: You may want to have a look at the 'this' keyword in javascript. It acts differently than other languages like Java/C#, and is kind of like an ever present reference to an object that serves as a context for your function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Seems weird everyone assumes it is an issue with `this`

Comment: Your function accepts an array name and an index of an item to be removed? Why are you rewriting the splice method?`window[array_name].splice(index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
removeItem(itemArray, index){
    itemArray.splice(index,1);
}
```

And, if selectedColors is your array, don't use quotation marks.

```
removeItem(selectedColors, 5);
```

Comment: so a string has a splice method?

Comment: I guess that 'selectedColors' is the array. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes this just did the trick! selectedColors array is stored in vue data object so I thought I needed to use this.selectedColors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are messing things up or it's confusing on what you are trying to do. You cannot `.splice` a string since `.splice` [only exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on arrays. You need to pass in an `array` to `removeItem()`.

I also noticed that you need to remove the `this` keyword in front of `itemArray`. `this` is not the `this` you are trying to reference.

See below, and let me know if it helps.

```js
function removeItem(itemArray, index) {
   itemArray.splice(index, index);
}
var itemArray = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
console.log(itemArray);
removeItem(itemArray, 1);
console.log(itemArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `this` references the context from which you call the function. What you could do is

```
removeItem.call(yourArray, index);
```

Then `this` would reference your array in your function. But in your case you can just remove the `this` because the passed in arguments are available without it.

Answer (score 0):

I can observe a general mistake here...

```
removeItem('selectedColors',5);
```

`selectedColors` is a string and not an array, `string.splice()` will always return an error. Make sure you pass the array to `selectedColors`.

```
let selectedColors = ["red", "blue"];
```